# React native, get value from url browser

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do i get the value of url from the browser? using the react native

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors while doing this?

Comment: Are you using webview to access this page ?

Comment: hi goodday , yes

Comment: pls add some minimal relevant code as web implementation (if it native code on the browser or web view), the package you use for navigating (react-navigation or react-router) and if its bare react native or expo project

Comment: Can you add your code? There are several ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make callbacks from the gateway website, then I recommend to use deep linking to handle flow between app and browser. Basically, your app will open the gateway website for payment, and depending on payment result, the website will make a callback to the app using its deep link. App then will listen to the link, take out necessary information and continue to proceed.

What you need to do is:

Set up deep linking in your app. You should follow the guide from official website (here) to enable it. Let pick a random URL here for linking, e.g. gatewaylistener

Set the necessary callbacks from gateway to your app. In your case, since you need to handle successful payment and failed payment, you can add 2 callbacks, e.g. gatewaylistener://success?id={paymentId} and gatewaylistener://error?id={paymentId}

Finally, you need to listen to web browser from the app. One way to do that is add listener right inside the component opening the gateway.

```
// setup
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      this.handleOpenURL(url)
    }
  }).catch(err => {})
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL)
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL)
}

// open your gateway
async openGateWay = () => {
  const { addNewOrderGatewayToken } = this.props
  const url = `${BASEURL}${addNewOrderGatewayToken}`
  const canOpen = await Linking.canOpenURL(url)
  if (canOpen) {
    this.props.dispatch(setPaymentStatus('checked'))
    Linking.openURL(url)
  }
}

// handle gateway callbacks
handleOpenURL = (url) => {
  if (isSucceedPayment(url)) { // your condition
    // handle success payment
  } else {
    // handle failure
  }
}
```